# Is it a code violation to have so many outlets and switches on a single breaker?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, circuit

My mother in law recently started renting a 3 bed 2 bath 2019 Nevada series single section mobile home. She is constantly blowing the same breaker which controls all of the switches and outlets (*except the master area*).  Bed and bath, laundry and kitchen counter area ceiling light goes out as well, even the outside outlets shut off.

I can fix almost anything in   RV'S and modular homes except for the electrical, I will leave that to the professionals.

Before I have her report this to the park that she rents from I wanted to see if this is a code violation  or if it could possibly just be her overloading the 15amp breaker that is blowing.

Red dots are for the outlets purple for switches that are on the same 15 amp circuit breaker:

[image]

Comment: Bathroom, laundry and kitchen are the key "must have dedicated circuit" areas. So this may actually be valid under code. Key question: Are there any portable heaters involved?

Comment: What type of breaker is it, GFCI?  What's plugged into the outside outlets?

Comment: When you say "laundry goes out", do the laundry room *receptacles* (where the washer is plugged in) stop working, or is it only the *light* in the laundry room/area that quits?

Comment: So I went to her home she has 8 outlets, 5 light switches and 2 supposed gfci outlets i say this because outlet next to 2nd bathroom sink has a sticker saying it is gfci but was unable to test yet.

Comment: Just the light in laundry room also my wife just informed me that her stove is also on that same breaker and i do know it is not a gfci breaker the outlets is what still need tested

Comment: "stove is also on that same breaker"? That would be a definite violation. Unless "stove" is really just a hot-plate or similar, but even then it should be on kitchen counter-top receptacles which should have their own circuits.

Comment: It is a normal gas stove and oven with a digital clock and timer

Comment: I _presume_ you live in the US, but where? While adoption of different versions of the NEC varies by locale, dedicated circuits in the kitchen isn't particularly new, but knowing which version of NEC you're on will be helpful.

Comment: So, we'll need a few dimensions to work this out.  Can you get us the width and overall length of the mobile home in question, as well as the length of the master suite, the length and width of the entryway, and the length of the living/dining area?

Comment: "I can fix almost anything but electrical" **you can't fix anything in a rental unit** without landlord permission, and most towns require a licensed tradesman to do serious e.g. electrical work in rental units.  (to stop both tenant incompetence, and slumlord cheapness).

Comment: Please take the [tour] (and don't YELL AT US. Answers don't belong in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Dining room, living room, bedroom and lighting receps all on the same circuit is totally legal under Code.  It's a severe case of min-max'ing for builder cost rather than occupant usability, but it's not illegal at all.  This "min-max"-ing is particularly strong in manufactured homes where a single factory builds tens of thousands; a guy can earn a year's paycheck by figuring a way to shave off $5 per unit. AFCI breakers are $40.

A gas stove that has a 120V plug-in is allowed either on general house circuits, or on the dedicated kitchen countertop receptacle circuits.  That is because of an exception that allows it on the kitchen countertop circuits, which normally don't allow any fixed appliances.

---

As far as "GFCI Protected" labels on plain receptacles, any GFCI device can feed other devices that are also equally protected.  That's legit.  Further, the labels are not just legit but *mandatory*. If you see a plain outlet that *you know* is GFCI protected from another outlet, and there's no sticker, *that's the Code violation*.   If you don't like the blue stickers that come in the GFCI package, feel free to make your own!

---

**Honestly, this is almost certainly a "Pilot error" problem,** and the user needs to be educated that electricity is not just magically infinite, circuits have limits **which are knowable**, and each appliance takes some amount **which is knowable**.  So there is no mystery here.

After some problems with trips, I skilled up my sweetie, who now knows how to find an appliance's nameplate and get amps, and divide by 120 if only watts are shown, and can recite off "Toaster 7, heater 7/13, hair dryer 12" etc.  And also knows which outlets are on which breakers (it's not hard in this house).

In a more complicated house, I would resort to labeling each outlet for circuit ID and ampacity.  I'm fond of whimsical names like Thor/Odin/Loki/Sif/Hulk/Groot for circuits, but whatever you like.

The gas stove has too small a current draw to even be worth calculating, e.g. cell phone chargers, internet routers and the like, as well as LED bulbs.  The gas range/oven is one of those: the onboard electronics might take 10 watts max, plus a 25-40 watt oven light; that makes 35-50W or 0.3 to 0.4 amps.

Comment: See my first comment on the question: "Are there any portable heaters involved?" Don't need an electrician to figure that one out!

Comment: @manassehkatz I notice OP did not answer that one.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question *if this is a code violation* I can tell you it is not an NEC violation, but not for the reason you would think. In NEC Article 550 which covers mobile Homes, after the first paragraph, there is an informational note. It basically tells you that the electrical system in your Manufactured Housing is regulated and inspected under the **Federal Mobile Home Construction and Safety Standard.** That means it is under a different set of rules other than the NEC.

The best way to fix an overload problem is to split the circuit into two circuits. Buy or borrow a clamp ammeter. Attach it to your circuit at the panel and unplug ever appliance that is attached to the circuit and turn off every light then one at a time, turn every light on and plug in and start each appliance checking the ammeter as you go. That way you will be able to see where you need to split the circuit. Then you need to find a low profile area to attached the new circuit.

I advise caution since Mobile Home devices are usually a punch down type device that are not standard equipment and they require a special tool to install them. In other words they are cheap. So you may have plan how to attach your new circuit prior to cutting some device loose at a box and proceeding (there might not even be a box at each device).

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Keep in mind this is a **rental**. Straight replacement of a switch or receptacle is one thing (whether technically legit or not). Splitting a circuit into two is not something a tenant should be doing.

Comment: Not only that, but FEMA mobile homes follow the 2005 NEC with the AFCI requirements eliminated.  And @manassehkatz mobile-home receptacles are *super weird* because they are so hyper-optimized for assembly cost savings, and a novice could well find themselves "in over their heads" just trying that!